# Artifactory Registry (Professional) vs Docker Registry

Tags: registry, artifactory, docker-registry

I have read about Artifactory Registry (from now, Artifactory) from their website, and it seems that AR is described as better than Docker Registry for production environment. However, I can't find any comparison matrix between the two. What specific features that Artifactory provides that Docker Registry doesn't?

For example, [I read that Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Authentication) provides more granular authentication and authorization mechanisms. But does that mean you can't do authorization using Docker Registry?

I am specifically interested in Artifactory Professional version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Granular Permissions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions) in Artifactory means that instead of just saying 'user x can access my registry' (i.e. adding a collaborator or assigning team and user permissions to your *entire* private registry in Docker Hub) you can specify *exactly* what specific images a user can access inside an existing registry without having to create separate ones to serve separate users or groups.  Artifactory also bundles a lot more features in terms of [security](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Security) compared to Docker Hub.

Check out the [wiki page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry#DockerRegistry-GettingStartedWithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry) about docker registries in Artifactory for the detailed explanation, but mainly what Artifactory offers for any package management system (including docker) is the ability to better maintain, trace, and manage your data and metadata - this includes extensive search capabilities using [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language) or from the [UI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry#DockerRegistry-SearchingforDockerImages), permission management as mentioned, having multiple registries - private or public, licenses, and a bunch of other [stuff](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Pro) that you can use that's already included when you get Artifactory.

Also, check this [blog post](https://www.jfrog.com/blog/docker-registry-to-production/) which explains the concept of why Docker images are problematic in production unless you take means to know *exactly* what you release.

Comment: Is there a comparison matrix between Artifactory Repository and Docker Trusted Repository? Reading the list of features provided by both Artifactory and DTR, it just seems like they all do the same thing. I am so confused. Both offer granular permissions with LDAP integration. Both offer integration with NFS. Both provide the ability to search and browse repos, integrate with CI and CD systems, and manage different settings. But where do they differ?

Comment: We took you're comment to heart and will prepare one - in the meantime I suggest you approach sales@jfrog.com to get a through response in a timely manner, I'm sure they will supply you with an answer that satisfies you.       Specifically for permissions though - Docker lets you control permissions for an *entire* repo (so user that has read permission can pull anything in there), Artifactory lets you control permissions *inside* that repository (so you can say user x can only pull specific images from a repo). Artifactory also integrates a wider range of authentication options than just ldap

Comment: Also, Artifactory's [CI Integration](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration) is *way* more advanced.    You can always request a [trial version](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/free-trial/#Pro) and give it a spin - decide for yourself before committing to anything.

Comment: btw JFrog just released JCR (JFrog Container Registry) which is a CE edition (so free with some limitations) that you can play around with before you decide what to use - more info about that [here](https://jfrog.com/container-registry)